# Any other libraries/packages other than ctypes that have the capability to have a button that just says Yes instead of Yes/No?

Tags: python, windows, ctypes

I want to make a pop up before a shutdown happens that lets users have the option to prevent that shutdown if they are still working. If they are still working on the computer, the a pop up will say "Are you still using the computer" and then have a button that just says Yes. So far, using the ctypes library, it has Yes and No.

```
def display_message_box():
   
    MB_YESNO = 0x04
```

Error:

```
ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "Daily Scheduled Shutdown.\n\nAre you still using the computer?", "Warning", 0x40 | MB_YESNO)`
```

Comment: Reword it to something like "Daily Scheduled Shutdown Supression.\n\nPress Okay to cancel daily shutdown." and use MS_OKAY?